# info messages causes a designproblem

Tags: css

Imagine I have

```
       <div class="infomessage">

            <p> message </p>
            <p> message2 </p>

       </div>
```

Due to I use some ajax that sometimes will overwrite this `<div>` with error messages, the design will fly up and down crazy (top and bottom). Those error messages is not much higher or lower than those 2 `<p>` messages above which is why I would like to use a fixed height. What kind of css code do I need to use to keep some kind of fixed height indside this `<div>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to use a fixed minimum height, you can use `min-height` to set a minimum height for an element disregarding its content:

```css
.infomessage {
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  min-height: 100px; /* <- */
}
```

```html
<div class="infomessage">
  <p>message</p>
  <p>message2</p>
</div>

<div class="infomessage">
  <!-- no content -->
</div>
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) for more information about `min-height`.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a `min-height` and `max-height` with the same values as `height`